# how to count rows grouped by multiple dates (In Symfony)?

Tags: mysql, symfony, group-by, count, query-builder

I am trying to  `count`  how many rows I have for last 3 days,
for example I have this table named **tab**  :

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-09 |
| 2 | 2021-12-08 |
| 3 | 2021-12-07 |
| 4 | 2021-12-08 |
| 5 | 2021-12-07 |
| 6 | 2021-12-08 |
| 7 | 2021-12-06 |

I want to get this as result :
2021-12-09 : 1
2021-12-08 : 3
2021-12-07 : 2

How can I do this in **Symfony** Framework  Please?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you might try something like this.

```
$qb->select("date, count(id)")
   ->addGroupBy('date');

$qb->getQuery()
   ->getResult();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).